# Abelian group is divisible if and only if its isomorphic to a direct sum of $\mathbb Q$ and quasicyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the fact that an Abelian group is divisible if and only if its isomorphic to a direct sum of $\mathbb Q$ and quasicyclic groups so I can study the proof. Can someone suggest me a reference?

Comment: In Hungerford's Algebra, somewhere in chapter 3 (I think in the injective, projective modules section), the result is established in a series of guided exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find it in Fuchs' “Infinite Abelian Groups” (volume 1).

However, the proof is not really so difficult. Here's a sketch.

Let $G$ be a divisible abelian group. Then the torsion part $t(G)$ is divisible as well and so it splits: $G\cong t(G)\oplus (G/t(G))$. Since $G/t(G)$ is torsionfree, it has unique division by integers and so it becomes a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.

It remains to analyze $t(G)$, which can be written as the direct sum of the $p$-components, like every torsion group. Hence we are reduced to a torsion divisible $p$-group ($p$ a prime).

This is perhaps the most difficult part. But some module theory can help: since $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian, every injective module is a direct sum of indecomposable modules. Thus we just need to characterize the indecomposable divisible $p$-groups (injectivity on $\mathbb{Z}$-modules is the same as divisibility).

In an indecomposable divisible $p$-group the socle must be simple and so the group is the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which is easily seen to be the Prüfer $p$-group.

Answer (score 1):

The structure theorem of divisible groups states that any divisible group is a direct sum of copies of the additive rationals and quasicyclic groups.
For references see for example [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=Vb38GspKia8C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=divisible+abelian+group+structure+theorem&source=bl&ots=VOb1JDuMNN&sig=uBr8zX2XyOSrJ1r5-QbFuIM_ZZU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBGoVChMIoOmupvOzyAIVRNEUCh1VJQCy#v=onepage&q=divisible%20abelian%20group%20structure%20theorem&f=false).

Comment: ”This paper has been withdrawn by the author. This expository note was withdrawn due to the triviality of its contents.”

Comment: Right, I found a "better" reference.

Comment: Which is Fuchs' book! `;-)`